# Como representar algoritmo em C para Pseudocódigo?

Tags: c, pseudocódigo

Eu tenho o seguinte código :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

int numeros[5];
int media;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Digite um número : ");
    scanf("%d", &numeros[i]);
}

media = numeros[0] + numeros[1] + numeros[2] + numeros[3] + numeros[4];

printf("\nMedia : %d \n\n", media);
printf("Número 1 : %d \n", numeros[0]);
printf("Número 2 : %d \n", numeros[1]);
printf("Número 3 : %d \n", numeros[2]);
printf("Número 4 : %d \n", numeros[3]);
printf("Número 5 : %d \n", numeros[4]);
```

Eu preciso passar este código para Pseudocódigo, mas não me lembro de como posso representar corretamente a parte do `for`.

Comment: para..................

Comment: Se for [neste formato](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocódigo), já tem um pseudocódigo de laço de repetição no primeiro exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, quero deixar claro de que Pseudocódigo não tem um modelo padrão, e tem simplesmente como propósito, representar um código de forma de que as pessoas que o vejam consigam entender de forma fácil. Logo se você não gostou do modelo que eu fiz aqui, acredito eu de que não mereça -1 pois como já disse acima, não tem padrão, caso você queira acrescentar algo a mais, por favor, me avise.

```
InicioAlgoritmo

Variaveis

numero : vetor[1..5] de inteiro
media,i : inteiro

Inicio

para i de 1 ate 5 faca
escreval ("Digite um número");
leia(numeros[i]);
fimpara

media <- (numeros[0]+numeros[1]+numeros[2]+numeros[3]+numeros[4]) / 5;

para i de 1 ate 5 faca
escreval("Número : %d %d, i+1, numeros[i]);
fimpara

FimAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, muito obrigado.